# Is there a way to copy a list of select files from one drive, and sort them into an identical file structure on another?

Tags: batch-processing, copy-paste

I am a video editor, and I have access to one of my repeat clients' servers, which is mounted as a network drive.  The connection is too slow, so I have to copy over any footage I want to use.  I like to keep it in an identical file structure, to make re-linking the footage on their end easy, but recreating it manually is extremely tedious and time-consuming, as is individually copying each file..

My question is, is there a way to take a list of select files and batch copy them to my own drive while keeping them in the same file structure?

Essentially, I want the file paths to look exactly the same except for the drive letter.

Comment: Surely `robocopy` can handle that.

Comment: It doesn't seem to be able to be that selective.  It seems like xcopy might be able to.  But I have zero prior experience working with this kind of tool so I'm struggling a bit with my research.